# How are prototype functions different than normal functions in javascript ? 

Tags: javascript

Javascript functions can be declared on a objects prototype like this:

```
<object name>.prototype.<variable name>=function(){
//
//
}
```

How it this different than following declaration?

```
<object name>.<variable name>=function(){
//
//
}
```

How are prototype functions different than normal functions in javascript ?

Comment: Please re-phrase into a real question that can be answered.

Comment: @gahooa: Why do you think this question can't be answered. It might be very high level, but it is still a question. You can always edit it to make it more clear. No need to down vote this simply because of grammatical mistakes...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186244/what-does-it-mean-that-javascript-is-a-prototype-based-language

Comment: Some doggone good stuff here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript/1598077#1598077

Answer (score 7, accepted):

functions declared on a base object's prototype are inherited by all instances of that object type.

For example..

```
String.prototype.foo = function () {
  return 'bar';
};
```

Now, every string will have the function foo() available.

`'test'.foo(); // returns 'bar'`

Read more about prototype-based inheritance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming)

Comment: +1 Also, it is worth explicitly stating that functions *and properties* declared on an object's prototype are inherited by all instances of the that object, *even those that have already been instantiated.*

Comment: Yes, good point. That last part is very important. The prototype acts somewhat as the last catch before a member is considered 'undefined' .. so modifying the prototype affects existing objects too.

Answer (score 16):

Prototype functions are instance functions, whilst normal functions are "static" functions. Functions declared on class's prototype will available on all instances of that class.

```
var MyClass = function(){
};
MyClass.staticFunction = function(){alert("static");};
MyClass.prototype.protoFunction = function(){alert("instance");};

MyClass.staticFunction(); //OK
MyClass.protoFunction (); //not OK

var myInstance = new MyClass ();
myInstance.staticFunction(); //not OK
myInstance.protoFunction (); //OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt and Igor have already provided enough code samples, but one of the best articles (short, correct and to the point) that you can read is [Prototypal Inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html), by Douglas Crockford.

There are also lots of different ways to facilitate inheritance through popular libraries ([Dojo](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/declare), [Prototype](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/class.html), etc)