# Object oriented keywords in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I could see interface,extends,declare keywords has been used in java script libraries

> lib.d.ts

as we use in Java.

For example

> interface HTMLObjectElement extends HTMLElement, GetSVGDocument { }

Why we can't use those keywords when we would like to apply oo design patterns to Javascript appliccations like Node.js

Comment: For starters, `.d.ts` are [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) definitions. Also you'll find with a bit of reading about ES6 that many of those features are being introduced.

Comment: Because JavaScript isn't a classical OO language. It's uses [prototypal inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186244/what-does-it-mean-that-javascript-is-a-prototype-based-language).

Comment: Javascript is prototype based language and not object oriented language. That#s why we can not use it.

Comment: I don't understand why I got so much down vote ?

Comment: Because the question is mostly about a subjective viewpoint. "Why doesn't language X do Y?" often has no good answer other than "Because it doesn't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) type definition file.

In order to use the same keywords you will need to code your Node.js application on Typescript and have a compiler that transform it into valid javascript.

Comment: Note it's possible to use the new ES6 keywords like `class` in a Node environment.

Comment: Yeah I was going to suggest ES6 too but I am not really familiar with it and a quick search show my that "interface" doesn't seem to be supported. So I went for the typescript answer. But a really valid note!

Comment: @Marty Yes, ES6 has some OO-like syntactic sugar. That is, in a kinda sorta don't look too closely type of way.

Comment: @Phylogenesis As you say, it is important to note that though I have mentioned keywords like `class` exist in ES6 it does not mean that they work in a traditional manner. They still produce typical JavaScript "inheritance".