# What are prototype, $.extend, and "return this" have to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm working on a legacy project, I'm confused with what this does

```
define(['jquery', 'components/BaseComponent', 'bootstrap'], function(
    $, BaseComponent, bootstrap
) {
    'use strict';

    return BaseComponent.extend({

        initialize: function(options) {

            BaseComponent.prototype.initialize.call(this, options); // what is this man?
            this.widgetOptions = $.extend({}, options); // what is this man?

            return this; // what is this man?
        },

        render: function() {

            BaseComponent.prototype.render.call(this); //again?


            return this; //again?
        }
    });
});
```

I have experience developing marionette app but above code still confused me. No documentation and the one who did this has left.

Comment: All of these are basic JavaScript patterns. It's entirely unrelated to other libs.

Comment: In fact, not only limited to JavaScript as chaining is applicable in many programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

## Inheritance and calling parent functions

First, some informations:

- Introduction to [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) [concepts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27775/Object-Oriented-Programming-Concepts)
- [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))
- [OOP in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
- [Inheritance with Backbone](http://jaketrent.com/post/backbone-inheritance/)

> ```
> BaseComponent.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);  // what is this man?
> ```

- **`BaseComponent`** is a constructor function ([understanding javascript constructors](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-javascript-constructors/)), which has the [Backbone's `extend` helper function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1874). This helper function wraps some of the complexity of [prototypal inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186244/what-does-it-mean-that-javascript-is-a-prototype-based-language).
- **`BaseComponent.prototype`** is the prototype of the parent class containing functions and properties.
- **`BaseComponent.prototype.initialize`** is a function of the parent class (`BaseComponent`), which we are overriding by defining a new `initialize` for this module.

Functions of a "class" are contained inside the [`prototype` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). By using the [`.call` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) on a function from the parent's prototype, we can call the function in the context of the current object.

## Making copy of objects

> ```
> this.widgetOptions = $.extend({}, options); // what is this man?
> ```

This is making a new object, in which properties of `options` are copied over. This is using [jQuery's `extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) and it makes a shallow copy.

This is a good pattern because:

1. it ensures that `this.widgetOptions` is an object,
2. it's a copy so you can safely modify the properties without affecting the received `options` object (which could be reused by the calling code).

## Chaining function calls

> ```
> return this; // what is this man?
> ```

This serves to [chain function calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), like this:

```
myView.render().lookImChaining().functionCalls();
```

Inside the `render` function, it is a Backbone standard. But in the initialize, it makes no sense since you never actually call the initialize manually.

From the [Backbone's doc](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render):

> A good convention is to return this at the end of render to enable
>   chained calls.

The [default view `render`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1252):

> ```
> render: function() {
>     return this;
> },
> ```

Comment: overriding means what? we can use the method available in `BaseComponent`? how does `prototype` come into play here? why not just `BaseComponent.initialize.call()` ?

Comment: overiding means that your BaseComponent has method named initialize and your posted code too have method with same name, and since you are inheriting from BaseComponent your code overrides the initialize method of BaseComponent. Try removing that prototype word from BaseComponent.prototype.initialize.call(this, options) you will get max callstack size reache error since initialize will keep calling itself.

Comment: @JessJordan I added lots of link to additional information.