# how to set the another view objects in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My app is designed that router is changed then rendering other view 
but, I don't know that how communication for created other view object.

**router.js**

```
    var app = app || {};
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var views = app.view = app.view || {};
    app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '*home': 'homeRoute',
            'about': 'aboutRoute',
            'contact': 'contactRoute'
        },
        initialize: function() {
            // create the layout once here
            this.layout = new views.Application({
                el: 'body',
            });
        },
        homeRoute: function() {
            var view = new views.Home();
            this.layout.setContent(view);
        },
        aboutRoute: function() {
            var view = new views.About();
            this.layout.setContent(view);
        },
        contactRoute: function() {
            var view = new views.Contact();
            this.layout.setContent(view);
        }
    });
})();
```

**view.js**

```
var app = app || {};
(function() {
    'use strict';
    //views linitalize
    var views = app.view = app.view || {};
    views.Application = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            // caching the jQuery object on init
            this.$content = this.$('#content');
            this.$loading = this.$('#loading');
        },
        setContent: function(view) {
            var content = this.content;
            if (content) content.remove();
            this.showSpinner();
            content = this.content = view;
            console.log(view);
            //content rednering
            this.$content.html(content.render().el, this.hideSpinner());
        },
        showSpinner: function() {
          this.$loading.show();
        },
        hideSpinner: function() {
          this.$loading.hide();
        },
    });
    views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({ });
    views.About = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function(){
        this.render();
      },
      render: function(){
        var template =  _.template("<strong>About page</strong>");
      }
    });
    views.Contact = Backbone.View.extend({
      my_template: _.template("<strong>Contact page</strong>");
    });
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="pills">
        <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="loading">load the page...</div>
    <div id="sumMenu"></div>
    <script src="lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/backbone.localstorage.js"></script>
    <script src="routers/router.js" ></script>
    <script src="views/view.js" ></script>
    <script src="views/app.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you look at this code, you'll understand. It's hard to communicate what I said above.

Look at the **view.js**, I wrote 3 views property (`home`, `about`, `contact`) and those contained code that doesn't run.

```
my_template: _.template("<strong>Contact page</strong>");
```

I really want to know that after object create, how to set the objects value and rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is heavily inspired by [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082149/1218980), but you need to **read the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/) (and also [Underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/)) to understand what's going on**, what you're doing and what needs to be done to add features to it. Otherwise, you'll always drift away from the working code into a new mess that you don't understand.

The Backbone doc is short and sweet and the [source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) is filled with comments. Don't read all of Underscore's doc, but read at the least the documentation for the functions you're using (like [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template)).

---

## The [Router `routes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes)

Since you copy-pasted the exact code from my other answer without first checking if it works, you copied a mistake that I made. **The more specific routes should be defined first and the catch-all route last**.

```
routes: {
    'about': 'aboutRoute',
    'contact': 'contactRoute',
    // put the catch-all last
    '*home': 'homeRoute',
},
```

When instantiating a new Router, its constructor calls [`_bindRoutes`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7da4ed73e7402baf614a50a6551d47ace68b5239/backbone.js#L1633-L1640) which parses routes from the last to the first.

> ```
> _bindRoutes: function() {
>   if (!this.routes) return;
>   this.routes = _.result(this, 'routes');
>   var route, routes = _.keys(this.routes);
>   while ((route = routes.pop()) != null) {
>     this.route(route, this.routes[route]);
>   }
> },
> ```
>
> Routes added later may override previously declared routes.

---

## The [`render` function](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render)

What do you think the following will do?

```
render: function(){
    var template =  _.template("<strong>About page</strong>");
}
```

So all that's doing now is:

- it creates a new function,
- puts it in a local variable named `template`
- and do nothing else.

or even this:

```
my_template: _.template("<strong>Contact page</strong>");
```

`my_template` property on views is not standard Backbone, so if you do nothing with it, it won't do something by itself.

To understand, you need to know that the *Underscore `_.template` function takes a template string as argument (and optionally a settings object) and **returns a new pre-compiled template function** which takes an object as an argument.* ([More info and examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148034/1218980))

Backbone view's `render` function is left to the developer to override. It should ideally render something and be [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077412/1218980).

A simple view could be:

```
views.About = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<strong>About page</strong>"),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    }
});
```

> A good convention is to `return this` at the end of `render` to enable
>   chained calls.

And you should be doing this because you're chaining calls in your code:

```
content.render().el
```

---

## jQuery and `el`

Why do you pass `this.hideSpinner()`?

```
this.$content.html(content.render().el, this.hideSpinner());
```

While it do change the HTML of the `#content` div with the view's `el`, using `this.hideSpinner()` returned value as a second parameter makes no sense.

**[jQuery's `.html` function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString) only takes one parameter.**

---

## Where to put a loading spinner?

**Not within synchronous DOM manipulation.** It's useless to put a spinner that before being seen is removed.

**A loading spinner makes sense when there is asynchronous loading** of some sort, and that you want to inform the user that the page hasn't crashed or froze.

Say you want to load news for the home page.

```
homeRoute: function() {
    console.log("showing the spinner");
    this.layout.showSpinner();

    var collection = new Backbone.Collection({
            url: "/you/api/url/for/latest/news" // simple example
        }),
        view = new views.Home({
            collection: collection
        });

    collection.fetch({
        context: this,
        success: function() {
            console.log("removing the spinner");
            this.layout.hideSpinner();
            this.layout.setContent(view);
        }
    });

    console.log("End of homeRoute function");
},
```

In the console, you'll see the logs in the following order:

```
showing the spinner
End of homeRoute function
removing the spinner
```

More information, see:

- [what's the difference between `el` and `$el` and what's a cached jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980)
- [JavaScript inheritance, Making copy of objects and Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519149/1218980)

Comment: thank you sir. your very kind :)
i have some more question that above the your answer 
i write **_bindRoutes** then construction call autoload it?
and also render **return this;** too?

Comment: @SeanSin `_bindRoutes` is a "private" function of Backbone's Router. It's called in any Router constructor. I included it in my answer as a reference. `return this` in render is a convention, I quoted the documentation on this. The default [`render`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7da4ed73e7402baf614a50a6551d47ace68b5239/backbone.js#L1348-L1353) does this by default and enables chaining function calls.